# Strange numbers buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Hi I have a problem on buddypress. There are strange numbers in the like section. Please see image.[buddypress activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHr7b.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to solve this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need to include. When you are ready, you can update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

These strange numbers are maybe icon which is provided by your theme or plugin. Make sure your all assets are loading. Check your "Developer Console" to verify if any stylesheets or fonts are missing.